# How would this course be called in english?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

Next year, I am going to attend a course in a french university called "Calcul scientifique".
I would like to find a good textbook (or at least a translation) on the subject but I cannot find the right way to name it.

What would it be called in english ?

The topics are :

- mathematical modeling of physical processes, mainly PDEs
- analysis on those PDEs
- approximation of the PDEs using finite difference methods
- numerical analysis on those methods (convergence, ...)

I can see that this involves PDEs, but I am not looking for a textbook regarding only PDEs, but "Calcul scientifique" in general. I know that a lot of these topics are covered in computational science, but that is not my goal either.

Comment: Mathematical methods for Physics ?

Comment: This looks like some survey type course on numerical analysis with applications to applied math. Perhaps a numerical analysis book would service. It might also be possible to look at previous websites for the course at the university, or indeed to just provide a link to the class website (unless you worry about some sort of self identification).

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I'll check that :)